# How can I filter Azure Pipeline runs using 2 or more tags?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I would like to be able to filter my pipeline runs using tags from Filter section in order to reach quickly to the pipeline run in which I'm interested.

I saw that when I'm using 1 tag, the pipeline runs get filtered successfully, but when I'm using 2 or more tags (ex: Release and Beta), the runs are not filtered correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the filter option '**`Tags`**' for the pipeline runs is '**`OR`**' rather than '**`AND`**'. In fact, same on other filter options.

So, when you select multiple tags under the '**`Tags`**' option, it would list all the pipeline runs which have any of the selected tags, not only the runs which have all the selected tags.

Comment: Can this behavior be configured to be only AND or only OR ?